# Inconsistent table borders with FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have some tables which render fine in IE and Chrome.  But in Firefox some of the border arbitrarily don't show or have different widths.  You can see an example [Here](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/test.html).  Below is the relevant css:

```
    table {
            font-size: 1.0em;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 3px solid #004C87;
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }


    th, td {
            padding-top: 7px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #004C87;
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: top;
            line-height: 1.3em;
    }
```

In the image below I took screen shots as it renders in the different browsers.  The black arrow depicts the situation where the line/border does not show.  The red arrow illustrates situation where the width is different.

If I were to repeat these tables the occurrences would be arbitrary.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Firefox? It looks great in FF 6.0.2. Are you sure you're not zoomed out a little in FF?

Comment: I too have 6.0.2.  As far as I know I am not zommed in.  Screen resolution is 1440x900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this as the answer as I'm convinced at this point you must be just a little zoomed out in Firefox. Try pressing `Ctrl+0`

If you compare the two tables in the image you provided, you can see that the bottom one is slightly larger than the top one.

Comment: Yep - You are absolutely right!!!!  Must have at one point pressed some extraneous keys to do that.  Thank you very much for your persistence.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue where borders were appearing when they shouldn't have been.
I resolved it with this:

```
border-collapse:separate;
```

I know it's not the direct answer, but the search brought me here.